# variables inside local functions in c s-function

Tags: c, matlab

I am trying to make an s-function block in matlab simulink.Here is the mdlOutput function.it gives me an error when i define local variables inside

```
//////


static void mdlOutputs(SimStruct *S, int_T tid)
{
real_T           *y    = ssGetOutputPortRealSignal(S,0);// no error
real_T           *x    = ssGetContStates(S);//no error
UNUSED_ARG(tid);
real_T           *a;// error:missing ';' before 'type'
real_T           *b=5.0//error: illegal use of this type as an expression
}
```

Not just real_T,I cannot define any type of local variables inside a function, other than the y and x that are already defined in the template.Using static variables at top is working fine.What could be the problem with normal variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it .I have to define variables before the UNUSED_ARG(tid) command

Comment: The reason is that older C standards didn't allow declarations to be put in between statements, and what `UNUSED_ARG` does is insert a statement that basically does nothing in release builds. Later versions of the standard have relaxed that rule, but it seems you are using an older compiler that doesn't support that.